# Get onClick button event in child

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react component similar to:

```
let TabComponent = React.createClass({
    getInitialState : function() {
        return {
            tubesArray: [ ],
            rows: 10,
            tubesPerrow: 10,
        };

    },

    render: function() {

        return (
            <div className={styles.drawingWrapper}>
                <button className={styles.tabButton}>
                    Up
                </button>
                <Drawing ref="drawing" tubesArray = {this.state.tubesArray} deleteTube={this.deleteTube}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

And its child component takes the array in state and maps it in an svg to several circle components called tubes:

```
let Drawing = React.createClass({

    renderTubes: function() {
        let deleteTube = this.props.deleteTube;
        return this.props.tubesArray.map((row) => {
            return row.map((tube) => {
                return <DrawingTube key={tube.id} row={row} tube={tube} delete={deleteTube}/>;
            });
        });
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className={styles.drawing} style={{"border":"1px solid black"}}>
                <svg onMouseUp={this.handleMouseUp} onMouseMove={this.handleMouseMove} onMouseDown={this.handleMouseDown}
                     ref="svg" className={styles.svg} viewBox="0 0 480 300" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
                    {this.renderTubes()}
                </svg>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

The Drawing Tube component then are many circles with their own state of selected or not selected:

```
let DrawingTube = React.createClass({

    getInitialState : function() {
        return {
            filled: false
        };
    },

    fillSVG: function(event){
        if(this.state.filled){
            this.setState({filled: false});
        }
        else{
            this.setState({filled: true});
        }
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
            <circle cx={this.props.tube.xPos}
                    cy={this.props.tube.yPos}
                    r={this.props.tube.diameter/2}
                    stroke="black"
                    strokeWidth="1"
                    fill={this.state.filled ? 'black' : 'purple'}
                    onClick={this.fillSVG}
                    onMouseDown={this.handleMouseDown}
            />
        );
    }
});
```

My question then is how do I get the Up button click event in the "Parent's parent" (TabComponent) to decrement the y position of the circle in the child's child?  Or more generally, how do I pass an onClick event down to the children so that they can react to the event?

I found a lot of information on how to "see" events from children on the parent by passing a callback to the children components, but none of my Google searching turned up anything on how to "see" an event happening in a parent component.

Also deeper in the philosophy of what's going on here, I am using an array for a data storage mechanism and then passing that down as props to the child to render the circles.  I need to find the right way for the child's child component to be tied to the array element that rendered it, or for the button click to be able to directly manipulate the array piece that rendered it.

Thanks in advance for any help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass events from parent to children, you can only set properties.

So you can either pass a counter/position to the component on `onClick` event, or also just good old [JS events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events)

Comment: Well I guess that answers it then,  I'll just have to go with the JS events.  Thanks for answering.

Comment: would it be possible to pass the button as a prop and add the on click event in the child?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be probably passing the value you want to subtract from the Y position as props to `<Drawing />` and then again to the `<DrawingTube />`.

Comment: Makes sense. But it should only decrement if the state of drawingTube is filled.  So it's like I need to see the event on the drawingTube and then pass that up to TabComponent through a callback, but how do I see that button event